# Woocommerce remove email field validation

Tags: wordpress, validation, woocommerce

I am using Woocommerce register form.

My requirement for the email field is optional therefore may I ask is there any hook I can use to remove the built in email field validation?

I have another hook to do the validation for that.

**List of available hooks**

https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/hooks/hooks.html

Answer (score 1):

I've used https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-checkout-customization/ as a reference in order to customize a checkout field.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'bbloomer_required_woo_checkout_fields' );
  
function bbloomer_required_woo_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
    $fields['billing']['billing_email']['required'] = false;
    return $fields;
}
```